# groupby two columns, then reset_index fails due to having the same name

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I made the following groupby with my pandas dataframe:

```
df.groupby([df.Hora.dt.hour, df.Hora.dt.minute]).describe()['Qtd']
```

after groupby the data is as follows:

```
           count       mean         std    min  25%  50%    75%    max
Hora Hora                                                             
9    0      11.0   5.909091    2.022600  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   10.0
     1     197.0   6.421320    4.010210  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   30.0
     2     125.0   6.040000    4.679054  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   50.0
     3     131.0   6.450382    5.700491  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   60.0
     4     182.0   6.401099    5.212458  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   50.0
     5     147.0   6.054422    5.402666  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   60.0
     6      59.0   6.779661    6.416756  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   45.0
     7      16.0   6.875000    5.123475  5.000  5.0  5.0   5.00   25.0
```

when trying to use `reset_index()` I get an error, because the index names are the same:

```
ValueError: cannot insert Hora, already exists
```

How do I reset_index and get the data as follows:

```
Hora  Minute  count
9     0        11.0
9     1       197.0
9     2       125.0
9     3       131.0
9     4       182.0
9     5       147.0
9     6        59.0
9     7        16.0
```

Comment: Please see the existing [18 questions on *groupby ValueError: cannot insert ..., already exists*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=groupby+ValueError%3A+cannot+insert%2C+already+exists+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first rename and then reset_index:

```
(
    df.rename_axis(index=['Hora', 'Minute'])
    .reset_index()
    ['count']
)
```